# Flutter UI testing (drive) on multiple devices

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

Is there a way to switch between devices while driving an UI test with flutter?
I have an app that synchronizes data across all instances. Typical scenario would be a ToDo app. User creates a todo for himself on his phone, which would appear on his tabled where he is signed in.
Any ideas on how to automate it with flutter drive? I basically need two instances of my app running while testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, there is a way to start different simulated devices from the terminal on macOS and tell flutter wich one to use. So, solution is to write different files for different steps of the test and then run it in a script one after another:

```
enter code here
open -a Simulator
xcrun simctl boot $iphone8_id
xcrun simctl boot $iphone8_id
sleep 10
# That works just great!
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app_1.dart --keep-app-running -d $iphone8_id
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app_2.dart --keep-app-running -d $iphone11_id
```

Check for all device id's of Simulator with the following command:

```
xcrun simctl list
```